# Android Shared Preferences Saving Highscore and Unlocks

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have 27 characters that I want a player to unlock by beating scores, e.g. if his score is greater than 200 he unlocks character #1. I have a hard time trying to do that.

I have a class for characters that contains its number, the score required to unlock it, and a boolean to check if he is unlocked. But when it comes down to saving, I can't do that.

The main game loop is in file `GameScreen`. It has a value `points` counting the score.

When `GameState` changes to `PlayerDead` I want to check if any new character has been unlocked, and whether the high score has been beaten to save points.

Please help, I'm struggling with it for over a week and I can't find a good tutorial for `SharedPrefs` because all of them apply to GUI based activity that saves the name and surname you entered.

Comment: What exactly isn't clear for you?

Comment: SharedPreferences is a storage tool. Here, you're talking about your game logic. There's no relation with SharedPreferences.

Comment: Yes it is, can someone cand add me on fb, skype or sth, so he can help me ? Im depressed right now, cuz It boders me a lot. I cant make it. I will explain in depth there.

Comment: What do you want to store in SharedPreference? User's Current score so that on resume next time he will retain the same score?

Comment: Nope, best preformance, because it's a runner game. So I need to save it like in fruit ninja in arcade mode. So player can see where he is, and his best score.

Answer (score 0):

if you need sharedPrefs I can help you.

I can give some some example code.

or you can send your code and error if you get one, we update it.

but sharedPrefs is a good idea for that ? if user goes to application settings and clears data of your app, all data will be lost.

why dont you try create a sqlite databade, save it into assets directory and use it?

Comment: Hm, I didn't thought of that. You think it will be easier? Cuz the code is pretty complicated. And the only tinhg left is saving highscore and unlocks. It's a runner game so I don't need to save many scores, only one. Displayed in right top corner like this: Best: 900 points.

Comment: yeah I got definetly understood you, and holding a database for just one row looks stupid, but I as I said if users clears data, it will be gone. using sqlie is not so complicated and not very easy of course. you cant do it with one line code. so maybe you can search for what people do for this in games like yours.

Comment: And can u give me a tutorial or hint how to do this. I'm so angry that saving one int value is so damn hard. Cuz if i manage to save it, unlocks for characters will be easy. But I can't do that. So if u can add me on fb or skype that I will show u my problem. Cuz my app is pretty complicated, and none of tuts covers this kind of problem that i Have.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple, you use SharedPreferences to store key-value pairs. You can either call

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

From the GameScreen and then define a constant:

```
public static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";
```

To use as the key for the saving.

In order to actually save, you need an Editor:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
//save data now, mPlayerScore is the score you keep track of
//if it's another type call putString(), etc
mEditor.putInt(KEY_SCORE, mPlayerScore);
//if that is the only thing you want for noe
//close and commit
mEditor.commit();
```

And in order to retrieve the saved score, during your onCreate() you can do:

```
public void getUserProgress() {
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
//no need for an editor when retrieving
mPlayerScore = mPrefs.getInt(KEY_SCORE, 0);
//second value passed was the default score 
//if no score was found
}
```

In order to check for new character s being unlocked, you can call the following code after every game:

```
private void checkForUserUnlocks() {
if (mPlayerScore >= MyUnlockableCharacter.SCORE_NEEDED_TO_UNLOCK)
   MyUnlockableCharacter.isUnlocked = true;
//and same for other unlockabld characters
}
```

There are other ways to access SharedPreferences, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I made a function public void SavePoints() to save points and copied the first line of code that U gave me. Than I added
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences; and now Mode_Private is underscored red and I don't know why.

Comment: Try Context.MODE_PRIVATE it was supposed to be all caps.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but now  getDefaultSharedPreferences causes an error. Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:GameScreen [line: 883] - SavePoints()
 - The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(int) is undefined for the type

Comment: Hi, I will edit answer, it should be PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: Can you help me via skype or fb or some kind of chat?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to store and retrieve Score from SharedPreference.

```
public static void saveScore(Context context, int score){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("SCORE", value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static int loadScore(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int score = sharedPreferences.getInt("SCORE", 0);
    return score;
}
```

Comment: OMG it actually works, I think, it has no errors! Thanks so much! So every time player dies i call saveScore? and every time I want to display score in menu what should I do?

Comment: You can have a local int variable store the score, and call saveScore only during onStop() or other lifecycles

Comment: just call `loadScore()` it will return the stored value.

Comment: My score is stored as int points, and I cant manage to use savescore because, I dont know what to type in arguments.

Comment: I have updated above code as per your requirement now use this and let me know is it working or not

Comment: Am I suppoused to  saveScore(context,points); call it like this in main game loop?

Comment: but I got a problem. It doesnt work, cuz points is ok but i dunno what to type as context arg, Is it package name?

Comment: from where did you want to call this method `saveScore(context,points)`, is it from `Activity` or any `View` or `Layout` which class is it?

Comment: I wan to call it from activity

Comment: When i used saveScore(context,points); this error showed up: Multiple markers at this line
 - context cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Line breakpoint:GameScreen [line: 533] -

Comment: If you are calling it from `Activity` then simply call `saveScore(YourActivityName.this, points)`

Comment: And if I wanna load what I should do? loadScore(AndroidFileIO.context);
  g.drawString(String.valueOf(AndroidFileIO.context), 400, 120, paint2); is it ok?

Comment: If you are loading score from an `Activity` then call `loadScore(YourActivityName.this);` else your `activity` name is `AndroidFileIO` then `loadScore(AndroidFileIO.this);` else you are calling from `view` or any `service` then preserve the context as a member variable and and pass that context directly to the `loadScore()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Read Sample;

```
public int Read() {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FileName",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();
        int mCounter = mSharedPrefs.getInt("Counter", 0);
        return mCounter;
    }
```

Write Sample;

```
public void Write() {
        SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("FileName",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putInt("Counter", 15);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
    }
```